# GCP health check on nginx with tomcat

Tags: tomcat, nginx, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-networking

I'm trying to set up health check on an instance with nginx listening on port 80 with a proxy pass to a tomcat listening on port 8080 but I get 302 responses. Here are the health check settings :

```
Host
myapp.com
Path
/
Protocol
HTTP
Port
80
Proxy protocol
NONE
Interval
5 seconds
Timeout
5 seconds
Unhealthy threshold
2 consecutive failures
Healthy threshold
2 consecutive successes
```

Any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Notice that you are getting the code 302 due the redirection, an HTTP health check is expecting the a HTTP code 200.
You have two options or change the port to 8080 or change the health check type to TCP, By using the TCP health check will only check if port 80 is open.

Here is a link to the health checks documentation [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/load-balancing/health-checks#supported_protocols)